# How to make a full offline backup of Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, backup

I am using ***Android Studio*** to learn how to make android apps for some days `(I am using Ubuntu)`. Now, I need to reinstall ubuntu, but I don't want to download anything of Android Studio again, as I have limited internet data and a slow network.
So, I want to take a full backup, so that I can re-use them after OS reinstall.

So, please tell me how can I make a backup of ***Android Studio***? Which directories/files I need to make copy of? or what should I do?